# <intent-filter> for WhatsApp audio shares

Tags: android, whatsapp, intentfilter, android-sharing

I want to be able to handle intents from WhatsApp when the user selects share on an audio clip. Several audio apps are able to handle it, but mine is not listed in the share dialog. My current `intent-filter` works for just about every other app. It is:

```
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/x-flac" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/flac" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/ogg" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/mp4" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/3gpp" />
            </intent-filter>
```

I've tried using the `*/*` mime type, and using the `OPEN_DOCUMENT` action to no avail. According to the docs, `file` and `content` schemes are implied by by `intent-filter`, is there another one I need to use for WhatsApp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy answer is we must have an intent-filter that handles `android.intent.action.SEND`